# Eclipse Plugin: How to run Launch-Configurations in a for-loop synchronously?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

Here is a simplified version of my code. `configurations` is an **array** of the type `ILaunchConfiguration`.

```java
for (int j = 0; j < configurations.length; j++) {               
   configurations[j].launch("debug", null);
}
```

I want to achieve that every `ILaunchConfiguration` only launches when the prior one is terminated. With my current code I have Thread behaviour. All configurations start simultaneously.

What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this in a simple loop as you will have to use an `IDebugEventSetListener` listener to listen for each process created by the launch terminating.

When you call `ILaunchConfiguration.launch` you get back an `ILaunch` object. You can then call `ILaunch.getProcesses` to get an array of `IProcess` objects that were created by the launch (there may be several processes created).

Set up an `IDebugSetEventListener` using:

```java
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
```

In the listener `handleDebugEvents` you can check for the processes finishing with something like:

```java
public void handleDebugEvents(DebugEvent [] events)
{
  for (DebugEvent event : events) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    if (source instanceof IProcess && 
        event.getKind() == DebugEvent.TERMINATE) {
      // TODO check if the process terminating is one you are interested in
    }
  }
}
```

Once all the processes for a launch have terminated you can do the next launch.